# authenticator for static html hosted using IIS 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, https, iis-6

I'm a beginner when it comes to web development. Currently I have a bunch of html files hosted using IIS 6 on a server. But pretty much everyone with the link can access the content.

What I'd like to do is hook up a logic to tell IIS whether to show the html page or not. I try to explain the steps below.

- website.com is hosted using IIS
- user clicks on the link `website.com/projectid/htmlcontent.html`
- Before showing the html page content IIS contacts a 'permission management logic' to see if it returns true or not (basically c# code that checks if the current user has access to project, on another application, with 'projectid' from the link)
- If true IIS shows the page to user, otherwise gives 401 error.

IIS hosted website is already available with me. The questions I have are here:

- What is the best way to codify this 'permission management logic', I mean is c# a good choice?
- how do I make the logic and IIS talk to each other?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the website frameworks provide this authentication feature, such as Asp.Net application Identity, applicable to `Asp.Net MVC`, `Asp.Net Core MVC`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity
Asp.net form authentication, available to Asp.Net webform website framework.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308157/how-to-implement-forms-based-authentication-in-your-asp-net-applicatio
Besides, IIS also provides the below feature to authenticate the client-side.
[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831496(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

if these are pure html pages. one way is to do the authentication and authorization process in one aspx page or in a better way in asp.net Generic Handler (.ashx) . check the authorization then read HTML files and
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(AllContent_as_String) all the HTML content.
so the actual path for HTML files remains hidden. you can even save them in database .
I hope this idea can help you.